# Deplyement WAR On Glassfish

Tags: hibernate, deployment, glassfish

i deployed my application on glassfish server 4.1. everything work wonderful until next day, when i tried to authentifie but i can't, my application can't access to my database to verify my username and my password. after redeployed it, it work again.
my ORM is hibernate 4.
Can you help me please.

Comment: yes that what happened !! i don't understand, me either

Comment: And now the people should guess what the problem is or what do you expect?

Comment: just ideas about the origin of this issues ? i think that's what this forum is for !!!!

Comment: No one will have any idea about the issue because you didn't describe your problem...

Comment: ok i try to give you more details. by the way think you for your time